# Roboelectric 3 compilation error

Tags: android, maven, robolectric

In my app I updated for `Roboelectric 2` to `Roboelectric 3`
On the next code:

```
final Dialog dialog = ShadowDialog.getLatestDialog();
final ShadowDialog shadowDialog = Shadows.shadowOf(dialog);
Assert.assertNotNull(shadowDialog);
```

I have strange complication error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (test-compile) on project tunneling-agent-lib: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] final ShadowDialog shadowDialog = Shadows.shadowOf(dialog);
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The type android.net.ConnectivityManager$NetworkCallback cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Before that everything worked (build with maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
    <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

What can possible cause that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add org.apache.http.legacy.jar which is in Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/optional to your maven dependency?